# Nativescript SQLite null values after execSQL queries

Tags: sqlite, nativescript

i have the following problem. I designed my litesql database over 'DB Browser for SQLite' and I'm stuck as soon as a query gets executed. The functions I am exporting are getting imported and used in nativescript-vue.

Webpack also copies the database with *.sqlite ending to the device. The android version I use is 9.

The way I initialize my db is;

```
 var Sqlite = require("nativescript-sqlite");
 var db;

 export function init() {
    if (!Sqlite.exists("test.sqlite")) {
       Sqlite.copyDatabase("test.sqlite");
    }

   new Sqlite("test.sqlite", function(err, dbConnection) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
      }
      db = dbConnection;
      console.log("connection successful")
   });
}
```

After running the function console shows 'connection successful'. The database is placed in the root of the app folder. That way it should pull the database?
Besides I got another question. How could I hide the database in the production?

So the way I execute the query is:

```
export function xxxx(**parameter**) {
    db.execSQL(
        "select random_id from random_table where some_id = ?",
        **parameter**,
        function(err, result) {
            console.log("result 1: " + result + " err: " + err);
        }
    );
}
```

The output is:

> JS: 'result 1: null err: null'

I'm not even sure if it opens the database in the right way?

Comment: Try using `db.get` for select statements. Besides what you mean by hiding database on production? If you like DB not to be part of source code then you should probably download it on the fly Or use paid version of the plugin which supports encryptions.

Comment: @manoj yeah exactly that was what I was asking for by hiding database on production. When I use db.get it tells me, my table doesnt exists. 'no such table' error

Comment: Then may be it's something specific to your DB, may be you can create a Playground Sample with a sample db file.

Comment: @Manoj I would say it's better when I create the DB through db.execSQL, because I have the whole create code of my database that is needed. Do you think I have the opportunity to save it as a file after creation? That way problems should be solved right.

Comment: What you mean by save it as a file? If you are talking about exporting the DB, yes it's possible. It may be easy to copy the DB post creation from iOS simulator.

Comment: @Manoj Yes, I mean exporting the database that was created through db.execSQL. Is there any example you may give? My app is based on android devices. The purpose of exporting the created DB is to have the opportunity using it on the next app run. It would be saved locally that way and I might open the pre-populated DB the next time.

Comment: @Manoj it's also not allowed to use multi-commands in the free version right? Like 8 table create commands. Should I use every time a Sqlite db instance for one table? Or could you prefer any way I could make it solid.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand quite right. SQLite is already persistent therefore your DB is pre-poulated / the way you left on last app run. Why you would want to export and use again?

Comment: @manoj I mean if we forget the way I import the database as in my example because it's not working. When we assume I create the whole database with its relevant tables through commands then there would be a DB which should be able to run. That's why I want to recreate the whole DB through commands and export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to export DB file from Android / iOS, you may use [nativescript-share-file](https://github.com/braune-digital/nativescript-share-file) plugin and pass the right path.

**Android**

```
const filePath = application.android.context
            .getDatabasePath("your-db-name.sqlite")
            .getAbsolutePath();

new ShareFile().open({
    path: filePath,
});
```

For iOS the path will be different,

**iOS**

```
const filePath = knownFolders.documents().getFile("your-db-name.sqlite").path;

new ShareFile().open({
    path: filePath,
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved using the pre-populated database already. I don't need to export it anymore but that would be also relevant for other features.